# Storm processing time

Tags: time, apache-storm

How can I get processing time (sec) for all bolts in topology when I have some amount of tuples? I'd like to probe storm performance with number of tuples/time/nodes.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Processing language?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Edited the question to remove the processing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure this type of performance then you have to write your own code to do it. There are some good options to help you do this:

1. [Storm metrics](http://www.endgame.com/blog/storm-metrics-how-to.html) (comes built in with Storm 0.9.0+)
2. [Metrics (formerly Codahale metrics)](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/)

The poor man's approach is to add a tuple start time when you begin processing a tuple and try to calculate it yourself but this is unreliable on a cluster due to many machines might have slightly different times.